# Chain wheres with joins ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, where-clause, chain

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
filter_categorys = params[:filter_categorys]
companies = Company.where('id_category = (?)', filter_categorys).joins(:subsidiary).where('zone = Nuñez')
```

And it's not working....

So, I need to get all my companies that have an id_category and that they have at least one subsidiary within the 'zone'.

I guess this is not the way... please HELP ! :D

Company.rb:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :subsidiary, :foreign_key => :id_company
    has_many :benefit, :foreign_key => :id_company
    set_primary_key :id_company
    self.table_name = 'tbl_companys'

end
```

Subsidiary.rb:

```
class Subsidiary < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company
    set_primary_key :id_subsidiary
    self.table_name = 'tbl_subsidiaries'

end
```

Comment: use `id_category IN (?)` (not an equal)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that is trying to fetch the 'zone' column on tbl_companys and its on tbl_subsidiaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "tell" the where clause that the zone is in the subsidiary table:

```
Company.where(id_category: filter_categorys).joins(:subsidiary).where(subsidiary: { zone: 'Nuñez' }
```

If it says "relation subsidiary was not found", try with:

```
Company.where(id_category: filter_categorys).joins(:subsidiary).where(tbl_subsidiaries: { zone: 'Nuñez' }
```

Comment: The second answer worked out just perfect !

I'm so thankful MrYoshiji !

Thanks :D !!!!!